# Do these facial lines have a name?

Tags: vocaloid

I've seen these markings in a bunch of art and I'm curious if it has a certain name or if it's just a popular design choice; I've seen it in the "Matryoshka" Vocaloid song, as well as other anime OCs across varying communities.

If anybody knows what is the name of these or if they even have a name, please enlighten my weeb mind!! Thanks in advance for anybody with more insight on these! :)

[image: art from the Vocaloid song, known as "Matryoshka."]

Comment: facial lines as in what's on their noses in the image you provided?

Comment: The first thing that came to my mind was "tribal face painting", but I'm not sure if that's the answer...

Comment: @Memor-X
Yes, I did mean the nose and under eye markings they have. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough! ^^;